# Is there a way to parse date using WinRT API?

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, windows-store-apps

I was looking for something like [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx) in modern Windows JavaScript apps, but couldn't find a thing: I hoped to find something in [Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.aspx), but that one appears to have only formatting capabilities and no parsing.

I need the API to be able to parse date time objects from user input with respect to OS regional settings. I know of existence of [moment+locales](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js) or [jQuery\globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), but didn't want to go down the path of external libraries if there is any native support. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

There is a browser built-in `Date.parse` API, but it doesn't support globalization, because there is no way to pass locale as a parameter AND it doesn't respect current OS locale either. Example: there are locales where 11/12/2015 can mean: Nov 12 and Dec 11. I need an API that can respect that.

Comment: Does this not work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/k4w173wk(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: It doesn't, because: 1) `Date.parse` is only guaranteed to parse RFC2822 or ISO 8601, results of parsing other formats may be unexpected; for example, parsing "16.11.2015" returns NaN; 2) `Date.parse` doesn't accept locale parameter, which means it is not possible to implement globalization using it (it could theoretically work for me if it used OS current locale for parsing, but that's not the case).